# sql cte with parameter in excel microsoft query

Tags: parameters, common-table-expression

When using SQL CTE with parameter in Excel Microsoft query as:

```
;with cte1 as (SELECT  ID ,Item.ItemLookupCode
FROM Item 
where item.Notes like  '%'+?+'%' ),
cte2 as (select ItemID from Trans
where Time between ? and ?)
select cte1.ItemLookupCode,cte2.
 ,cte2.ItemID
from cte1  join cte2 
on cte1.ID = cte2 .ItemID
```

I receive the following  Error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Invalid Parameter Number
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Invalid Descriptor Index

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and after a lot of playing around with modifying the way parameters are passed, here's what I found:

Parameters work well with SQL queries without CTE. This looks like [an Excel bug, for which the ticket has been closed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/683858/invalid-parameter-number-invalid-descriptor-index).

Comment: Thanks i will try it :)